# Write files in usb when connect by /etc/udev/rules.d/

Tags: usb, udev

I am trying to write some files in usb when connect it in linux..
Actually, I have a file in in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` with:

```
ACTION=="add",  ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="9FE8-99G3", RUN+="/usr/bin/sudo -u myuser /home/myuser/Scripts/mycrazy.sh"
```

In `mycrazy.sh`, I have:

```
## Path to mounted device
PATH_USB=/run/media/myuser/9FE8-99G3

mkdir $PATH_USB/some_folder

mkdir /home/myuser/Documents/another_folder
```

The first mkdir, doesnt works. But the second, works.
How can I write files in usb? Is missing something in my script?

Comment: It could be due to a small delay took by udisk to mount the partition after it does notice `/dev/sdxY` as your script does. But your script is so fast. Try putting a short delay at the beginning example  `sleep 3` , you may lower it if  it does work

Comment: Nothing buddy.. Before the first mkdir I past the sleep.. Does not work.

Answer (score 1):

- What works for me, adding delay (`sleep`) and `disown` the script that has delay using an intermediate script.

  > **`RUN{`**`type`**`}`**
  >
  > ```
  > ...
  >        This can only be used for very short-running foreground tasks.
  >        Running an event process for a long period of time may block all
  >        further events for this or a dependent device.
  >
  >        Starting daemons or other long running processes is not appropriate
  >        for udev; the forked processes, detached or not, will be
  >        unconditionally killed after the event handling has finished.
  > ```

  **source:** [`man udev`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man7/udev.7.html)
- There a similar case here: [Why do my udev rules run if I use udevadm trigger, but NOT at boot time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445735/why-do-my-udev-rules-run-if-i-use-udevadm-trigger-but-not-at-boot-time). [*Fëamarto's answer*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445735/why-do-my-udev-rules-run-if-i-use-udevadm-trigger-but-not-at-boot-time/635477#635477) seems better than my solution here. It waits till its file system is ready in `rw` mode. You may give it a try.

  Because this is a USB drive, it can be removed before mounting. The script will stay alive till next reboot or it get plugged again (which trigger another instance) and mounted.

  One way to fix that is to check if related `/dev/sdxY` still exists. on each cycle.
- Here is my setup:

  1. `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-sneetsher-tests.rules`

     ```
     ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="6664-B2DA", RUN+="/usr/bin/sudo -u user /home/user/mycrazy.sh"
     ```
  2. `/home/user/mycrazy.sh`

     ```
     #!/bin/sh

     /home/user/mycrazy2.sh & disown
     ```
  3. `/home/user/mycrazy2.sh`

     ```
     #!/bin/sh

     PATH_USB=/media/user/MYFLASH3
     sleep 5
     mkdir $PATH_USB/some_folder
     ```