# udev script doesn't run in the background

Tags: usb, bash, scripts, udev

I'm having trouble getting a script run by udev to run in the background on usb insert.

My udev rule seems to work, since it definitely calls the script, but no matter what I do, I can't get bash script to run in the background, so it blocks.

### For Reference:

#### My udev rule:

`ATTRS{idVendor}=="125f", ATTRS{idProduct}=="db8a", SYMLINK+="usb/adata%n", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/abe/.Xauthority", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", OWNER="abe", RUN+="/home/abe/bin/usb-adata_udev.sh"`

#### My bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $ACTION == "add" ]]; then
    # I've tried many variations on this, none seem to work
    (su abe /bin/bash -c "/home/abe/Documents/Programs/USB\ Sync/usb-in.sh") &
fi

if [[ $ACTION == "remove" ]]; then
    /home/abe/Documents/Programs/USB\ Sync/usb-out.sh &
fi
```

#### the background script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#echo $ACTION > "/home/abe/Desktop/test.txt"

if [[ ! -d "/media/abe/ABE" ]]; then
    # for testing
    sleep 10
    #udisksctl mount -b /dev/usb/adata1 &> "/home/abe/Desktop/test.txt" 
    #rsync --update /media/abe/ABE/Files/db.kdbx /home/abe/Documents/db.kdbx
    echo "FINISHED" >> "/home/abe/Desktop/test.txt"
fi
```

The usb is doesn't get mounted by nautilus until the 10 seconds are done, and the udisksctl command gives me the error `Error looking up object for device /dev/usb/adata1` when uncommented, which makes me think that the udev rule hasn't even finished making the symlinks.

Note that the script works just fine when I run it from my terminal and not udev

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`RUN` could be used only for short tasks.

> **`RUN{`**`type`**`}`**
>
> ```
> ...
>        This can only be used for very short-running foreground tasks.
>        Running an event process for a long period of time may block all
>        further events for this or a dependent device.
>
>        Starting daemons or other long running processes is not appropriate
>        for udev; the forked processes, detached or not, will be
>        unconditionally killed after the event handling has finished.
> ```

**source:** [`man udev`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man7/udev.7.html)

You may use `disown` that will detach that previous process from the current shell.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $ACTION == "add" ]]; then
    # I've tried many variations on this, none seem to work
    (su abe /bin/bash -c "/home/abe/Documents/Programs/USB\ Sync/usb-in.sh") & disown
fi

if [[ $ACTION == "remove" ]]; then
    /home/abe/Documents/Programs/USB\ Sync/usb-out.sh & disown
fi
```

It is similar case as [Write files in usb when connect by /etc/udev/rules.d/](https://askubuntu.com/q/646011/26246) and may be you to look to this too https://askubuntu.com/a/635477/26246 by Fëamarto, nice recursive trick which wait till partition is mounted.

---

**Update**

`udev` changed much lately in these years. It is become part of `systemd` and more confined. Here are the current options:

- Set `udev` rule to [trigger a `systemd` service](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-systemd-and-udev-rules.html).
- Set `udev` rule to [run a script scheduling the job using `at`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804754/long-running-udev-script-on-ubuntu-16-04).
- A user-space script (python/pyudev, etc) that watches for the target `udev` event.

Comment: Do you expect the disown to make it work? I am in a very similar situation, calling the script with `&` in `RUN+=`, and the script runs a `nohup bash -c "stuff" & disown`, yet the command `stuff` dies immediately, if at all started.

Comment: @Gauthier, no sure, `udev` changed much lately in these years. Let me update my question, at least give a hint.