# Long running udev script on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, 16.04, scripts, udev, systemd

On Ubuntu 14.04 I have a long running bash script with a simple udev rule that works perfectly like this:

```
ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="block", RUN+="/opt/script.sh"
```

On Ubuntu 16.04 things aren't going so well.  The script starts to run but then gets killed before it completes.  I then tried changing my udev rule to call a warapper script which would detach the script.  I tried:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
nohup /opt/script.sh  &
```

Then I tried:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
/opt/script.sh | at now
```

To no avail.

I then tried to create a systemd service...

```
ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}=="justrunthescript.service"
```

/etc/systemd/system/justrunthescript.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Just run the script

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/script.sh
```

Which I got to run the script at some point, but my script relies on udev parameters like $ID_FS_TYPE which don't get passed in this way.

I think what I want is pretty simple, just insert a disc and run my script from a udev rule and don't kill the script.  What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Realized I needed to do:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 echo /opt/script.sh | at now
```

Comment: Would you accept your own answer as this what works for you. I saw before a method using process detachment (`disown`) as in https://askubuntu.com/questions/445735/why-do-my-udev-rules-run-if-i-use-udevadm-trigger-but-not-at-boot-time . But the scheduling (`at`) as you have used it here is simpler.

Comment: This should be added to the `udev` man page.