# udev rule to run gpib_config

Tags: usb, udev

I am using linux-gpib package and Keithley's KUSB-488A (gpib-usb converter) on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It is installed properly and I can successfully command my devices using `ibtest` utility. But before that, everytime I disconnect and reconnect the device I need to run `gpib_config --minor 0` inorder to initiate the drivers.

I wanted it to run automatically everytime a connection is made without having to run explicitly. So, a `udev` rule is what I thought of and wrote the following:

```
KERNEL=="gpib[0-9]*", ENV{DEVPATH}=="/devices/virtual/gpib_common/gpib0", RUN+="/usr/sbin/gpib_config --minor 0"
```

based on what I got from:

`udevadm info /dev/gpib0`

```
P: /devices/virtual/gpib_common/gpib0
N: gpib0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/gpib0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/gpib_common/gpib0
E: MAJOR=160
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=gpib_common
```

But this didn't help me when I restarted the `udev` rules. 
What I have observed, if I reboot the pc itself then on first connection I am able to run `ibtest` without explicit execution of `gpib_config`.

Please help me where I am lacking?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you got `/dev/gpib0` on the first time after reboot, the next reconnection is on `/dev/gpib1` and each time you reconnect it get incremented like in USB storage.

On your first connection, you got:

```
E: DEVNAME=/dev/gpib0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/gpib_common/gpib0
```

On second one, I expect:

```
E: DEVNAME=/dev/gpib1
E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/gpib_common/gpib1
```

So that rule never run on any reconnection, As `ENV{DEVPATH}` in the rule fixed at `0`. Another point, in your case `DEVNAME` & `DEVPATH` are very related (if I can't say: they are the same), so `ENV{DEVPATH}` does not add any thing to the rule. Try: `ls -l /dev/gpib*`, you should find a symlink:

```
/dev/gpibX -> /sys/devices/virtual/gpib_common/gpibX
```

So keep you rules simple:

```
KERNEL=="gpib[0-9]*", RUN+="/usr/sbin/gpib_config --minor 0"
```

BTW, this rule is run multiple times, at least it is run twice (2): On device connection & on device disconnection. I'm not familiar with hardware, if you need it that command only when device get connected add `ACTION` to the rule:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="gpib[0-9]*", RUN+="/usr/sbin/gpib_config --minor 0"
```

Comment: The linux-gpib driver always tries to open `/dev/gpib0` port only. Next when I tried 

`udevadm monitor --environment --udev`

I could see the actual characteristics of gpib-usb converter and then I changed my `udev` rule to:


`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="3923_725c_01123B73", RUN+="/bin/sh -c '/usr/sbin/gpib_config --minor 0'"`

It started to detect the device as I wanted it to but sometimes I found this not working when I reboot pc.

Comment: @AshishSharma , Do you mean (1) it doesn't work sometimes when machine rebooted with the device connected, to fix it you unplug & plug it again? Or (2) It doesn't matter if it was connected while reboot. Another thing, what's the name & path of the rules file you had used?

Comment: Yes, I would select option (1) with an addition that it happens every time I reboot the pc with device connected. Once I disconnect and then re-connect the device, the rule picks it up and it works fine. My rule name is `my-gpib-dev.rules` and it is the same I commented earlier.

Comment: @AshishSharma , it seems to me same case http://askubuntu.com/q/445735/26246 , the event comes while root file system is still in (ro) read-only mode , could you try both solutions there and vote up the one that works for you.